# Does Intel Iris UHD 630 support 3 1080p monitors?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, cpu, intel-graphics

I'm building a set of office PCs containing the i5-8600 CPU. Most people use three monitors and I would like to avoid having a dedicated GPU.

Intel claims to support a three monitor setup using their integrated GPUs, but the info is quite outdated.

The closest thing I found is this Chipset/iGPU support page, which was not updated for quite a while and mentions nothing about the UHD630 and 300 series chipsets.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000025672/graphics-drivers.html

So my question is, does anyone here have a first-hand experience with running three 1080p monitors using just the Iris UHD630 iGPU included in i5-8600?

EDIT: I have not chosen a motherboard yet, but I'm looking at B360 based boards. Feel free to recommend a board.
Additionaly, does the type of output ports matter for this use case? Do all-digital (DVI, HDMI, DP) mobos have better chance of working rather than mixed A/D (VGA,HDMI,DP) outputs?

Comment: https://communities.intel.com/thread/124698 says it can be done as does https://www.intel.vn/content/www/vn/vi/support/articles/000025671/graphics-drivers.html and https://www.dell.com/support/article/bb/en/bbbsdt1/sln295251/how-to-configure-u2415-monitor-daisy-chaining-on-intel-hd-graphics?lang=en but much more is required. Does your motherboard and its chipset support three monitors as well? Please confirm that, as you have not specified the motherboard nor its chipset. Click on `edit` above at left to add that useful information.

Comment: Are you talking about Intel® Pro Graphics 630?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have such an experience, but you may see this video for real testing :
[Free Trash or Hidden Treasure? - Intel's Coffee Lake UHD 630 iGPU Benchmarked!](https://ru-clip.net/video/4JBVem1cslg/free-trash-or-hidden-treasure-intel-s-coffee-lake-uhd-630-igpu-benchmarked.html)

You may see that the UHD 630 has problems for showing video or gaming
on a single screen, in both 1080p and 720p.

You will also see that even a cheap GPU like the GT 1030 runs rings around it.

Conclusion: Feasible according to the specs, but better not be very ambitious.

Comment: The machines will be used solely for Visual Studio and watching Youtube videos. 3D performance is not an issue.

Comment: The Youtube videos have an interest in not playing full-screen.